# how to add image to picturebox from imagelist

Tags: c#

Hi I have an Imagelist and a picture box.  I want to add the image to my picture box.

I tried like this

```
picbox.Image = imagelst.Images[0];
```

but it didn't work.
Visual Studio does not let me to write images after imagelist

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me. So, explain us what's wrong. What do you mean with "*didn't work*"?

Comment: ı mean when ı write picbox.Image = imagelst1.Images[0]; ıt underlined my code  and said doesnot exist int the current context

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? Can you write the code you're trying to use inside its class please?

Comment: macro thanks for your help ı found the problem . ıt was "i" visual studio named the item "ımageLıst"  but ı tried like this "imageList" :)

Answer (score 7):

It works, I think you don't have set an image in imagelist.

1. I set an image in imagelist.
2. I set this code.

   ```
   namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
   {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
           public Form1()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }

           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. It works.

[image]

Comment: visual studio doesnot let me to write imagelsit1 ıt just show ımagelist ı couldn not find the problem

Comment: Drag and drop imageList control from toolbox into the form. It will will be automatically named as imageList1. Then only you will be able to use  imageList1.Images[0]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but from the OP's comments, I think he does not have a instantiated imagelist object.

Drag an imagelist control onto the form, that will be "imagelist1" by default. You can rename it to what you want and then use it.